# How to Check if a Client is Still Connected c++

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, recv

I want to check using sockets whether a client is still connected to the server. I saw that the revc function gives me the status of the client but it is not working as I expect (sometines client did not disconnect and the revc function thought he was). 
I got this code:

```
if (recv(client->getSocket(), rcmsg, 1024, 0) <= 0)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < this->clients.size(); i++)
        {
            if (*(this->clients[i]) == *client)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)
            this->clients.erase(this->clients.begin() + i);
        closesocket(client->getSocket());
        std::cout << "disconected: socket = " << client->getSocket() << ", ip = " << inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr) << endl;
```

There is another solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to be certain your client is still there is to implement a request-response protocol between server and client that includes an "are you there" request which must be responded to. Other methods are less accurate in their results.

Comment: @mah That is certainly a way but it's not the only way.

Comment: @EJP are there other ways which are not subject to misreporting?

Comment: @mah One could use an underlying _heartbeat protocol_ (was it `KEEPALIVE`?).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: TCP keepalives, via `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE)`, or `WSAIoCtrl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)` on Windows 2000+.

Comment: I thought about that solution but what if the client's internet falls, the client can not send me a message of disconnecting

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that should tell the protocol stack to not drop the connection due to a timeout but does it give you a way to know the client is still there, or just that the client was there within the heartbeat period? I'm not being rhetorical, I don't know the answer. (Intuitively it would seem the answer is the latter, but if that period is or can be set to be small enough they might be effectively equal.)

Comment: You should also check the error message. Not every type of `recv` failure indicates the client is disconnected

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember where TCP/IP came from.

It's a communications protocol stack that's designed to withstand an all-out nuclear war.

That means, telegraph poles being vapourised, radio links intermittent or no longer there, telephone exchanges no longer being there... and it still had to work.

In this context, define "connected".

A TCP "connection" is merely two distinct hosts believing that they're connected, and somehow packets are routed to the hosts eventually by the remaining routers on the network.

This is why there is a whole host of protocols we never even think about, for example RIP (Routing Information Protocol) who's job is to discover the remaining links after the bombardment.

There is really no such thing as "connected". There is simply the time elapsed since you received a packet from the remote host. That's it.